# Data Retrieving for the stored data in SharedPreferences either through ShPrefs or XML Parser

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application, I've been able to successfully store the favorite contacts on to the SharedPreferences in to a file named "PACKAGE.xml' in the default location -->  data/data/applicationpackage..../sharedprefs/PACKAGE. And Currently, the XML looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<map>
<string name="CONTACT 0">Helen : (432) 341-1343</string>
<string name="CONTACT 2">Alex Zun : 1 234-321-231</string>
<string name="CONTACT 1">Gazer : 1 312-345-452</string>
</map>
```

I do understand that we can use either XML Parsing or retrieve data through SharedPreferences. 
Can you guys help me guide which is the better option and also provide a sample on each of the case...

Later I would like to put this data on to the ListView and in a custom row layout.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: While you can use an `XmlPullParser`, SharedPreferences are generally supposed to be read with the `SharedPreferences` class, not directly like this.

Comment: @matiash - Can you provide a sample how ? taking my stuff details as the example..That would help me doing so..

Comment: @matiash - As per your suggestion, used SharedPreferences to retrieve the data from them. Updated my answer in the below. I think instead of making the XML Parser, your suggestion helped me keep it simple...

Comment: I was going to provide an example, but I forgot. Sorry, but I'm glad you were able to solve it.

Comment: Npbs..your hint helped me get going..sometimes, that much is more than enough..but NOT always though :). Now I'm struggling to bring that data on to the ListView and on to the custom-row-layout... :( Any hints ?

Answer (score 2):

[Android Documentation for XMLParsing](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

The documentation has an example how to parse a xml using **XmlPullParser** with a **InputStream**, you can easily change that to read from a String ([LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)).

[Something like this:](http://pastebin.com/Ea0g3tdy)

```
public class XMLParser {

    private static final String XML_TO_PARSE = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"true\"?>"
                    + "<map>"
                    + "<string name=\"CONTACT 0\">Helen : (432) 341-1343</string>"
                    + "<string name=\"CONTACT 2\">Alex Zun : 1 234-321-231</string>"
                    + "<string name=\"CONTACT 1\">Gazer : 1 312-345-452</string>"
                    + "</map>";

    private XmlPullParser mParser;
    private static final String NS = null;

    public XMLParser() {
            try {
                    mParser = Xml.newPullParser();
                    mParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    mParser.setInput(new StringReader(XML_TO_PARSE));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                    //
            }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private HashMap<String, String> parse() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            while (mParser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (mParser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                            continue;
                    }
                    if (mParser.getName().equals("string")) {
                            readString(mParser, hashMap);
                    } else {
                            skip(mParser);
                    }
            }
            return hashMap;
    }

    private void readString(XmlPullParser parser, HashMap<String, String> hashMap) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, NS, "string");
            String contactName = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
            String contactInfo = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
            hashMap.put(contactName, contactInfo);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, NS, "string");
    }

    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            int depth = 1;
            while (depth != 0) {
                    switch (parser.next()) {
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            depth--;
                            break;
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            depth++;
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

**PS:** I do not test it.

[]'s

Comment: Thanks @Felipe. Let me implement and see it making work.

Comment: I've implemented a simple solution to have the sharedpreferences data retrieved as per matiash's suggestion and updated my answer above. Yet to work on how to bring that data on to the ListView with custom-row-layout. Let me know if comments on my answer to improve it further. Even though I've not used your code, but your suggestion is valuable for sure. Hence Accepted it as the same could be helpful others as well.

Answer (score 0):

***Updated Answer by me***

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PACKAGE";
SharedPreferences preferences;
int count = 0, i = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.favcontacts_list);
        tV_Contacts_list = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tV_Contacts_list);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        for (count = 0; count <3; count++) {
            String contacts_list = preferences.getString("CONTACT "+count, null);
            tV_Contacts_list.setTextSize(15);
            tV_Contacts_list.append("\n       "+ i +". "+ contacts_list);

            i++;
        }
   }
```

With the above code, I'm able to retrieve the contacts which were saved in SharedPreferences File `"PACKAGE.xml"` without issues.

Sharing my answer here such that it can help others in SO in case. Now, My next aim is to bring these details to ListView and through user-defined row layout.

Thanks..